# Jo HTML framework on Symbian

Tags: javascript, webkit, mobile-website, sencha-touch

What is the experience using the [Jo](http://joapp.com/) web framework on [Symbian S60](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S60_%28software_platform%29) (AKA Symbian^1) or Symbian^3 either directly in built-in browser or via [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap)?

Is there any web framework for Symbian OS and [Windows Phone 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone_7) (I was using Sencha Touch, but this is not compatible, so I am looking for something lighter/smaller probably...)?

Comment: I've heard Brian Leroux of PhoneGap fame talk very positively about Jo, but I can't say it was specifically in the context of Symbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a global idea.

The Jo HTML 5 framework is compatible with:

- iOS
- Android
- Symbian
- WebOs

And not compatible with

- Windows mobile
- Windows phone
- Blakcberry OS
- MeeGo
- Maemo
- Bada
- Java ME

[Mobile Frameworks Comparison Chart](http://www.markus-falk.com/mobile-frameworks-comparison-chart/)

NOTE: This is only global, it is possible that not all of the Symbian (or other) devices are supported.

Comment: Nice - but it is only the first step... There are few relevant Symbian OS version on the market - S60 5th (Symbian^1), Symbian^3, Anna and Bella with different web browsers... Also the question is if the comparison chart is based on the real experiences (i think no) or the release notes or information of the framework developers...

Comment: You are right, this is only the first step and this gives only a global  idea about what kind of OS it supports. Though I wasn't there when the frameworks where tested, the website does state that the research was done by itself. By real experiences not what the framework maker says.